# Работа скрипта php с учетом переменной записанной в HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Есть INPUT:

```
Длинна пароля<input type="tel" placeholder="" value="12"  id="passHeight" maxlength="2" onclick="this.select();" required pattern="[0-9]{,3}" style="display: inline-block;">
```

PHP:

```
$length = 12;

        function getPassword() { 
            global $length;
        $glength = $length;                                                                         // Возвращает валидный пароль
        $password = getRandomPassword();
            do {
               $password = getRandomPassword();
            } while(iconv_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') != $glength);
            return $password;
        }
```

Как можно сделать так чтобы в переменную `$length` записывалось значение из инпута? 
Пробовал аякс вызовом:

```
var str = 15;
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://generator:91/index.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: {post_data: str},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data['value']);
  }
});
```

php

```
$data = $_POST['post_data'];
$response = array();
$response['value'] = $data;
echo json_encode($response);
```

изначально я хотел заносить переменную из инпута заносить в в js, а потом уже аяксом в скрипт php
но вроде как сначала php скрипт исполняется, а потом уже клиентская часть, так получается в аякс вызове нет смысла?
В общем я в тупике, как вообще можно это реализовать?

Comment: Вы вообще что хотите сделать? Есть инпут вам его надо заполнить и отправить на сервер? `AJAX` - используют для того, чтобы не перезагружать страницу, т.е. заполнили инпут, жмете кнопоку - отправить. а эта кнопочка вызывает `ajax`, он вам вернет результат. Либо при нажатии на кнопку можно отправлять форму стандртным методом `<form>`

Comment: @Manitikyl Нужно сделать генератор паролей, сие действие которое пытаюсь сделать - отправить число, которое отвечает за длинну пароля. Пробовал только что <form action> столкнулся с тем что меня 
пересылает на php скрипт, число конечно передается, все ок, но я уже нахожусь на другой странице

Comment: Сделайте через `ajax`, чтобы вместо отправки формы, у вас вызывался ajax.

Comment: @Manitikyl т.е сделать кнопку отправляющий ajax-вызов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Основной файл:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form method="post" id="ajax_form" action="" >
      <input type="text" name="post_data" value="TEST" /><br>
      <input type="button" id="ajax_click" value="Отправить" />
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#ajax_click").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/test.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#ajax_form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
      return false; 
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.php**:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['post_data'];
```

Если в консольке увидим результат (а именно: после нажатия кнопки должен выводится текст который в инпуте), то все норм.

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное)